# Is it possible to use a vector in a PROC SQL case Statement?

Tags: sql, vector, sas

I have a short vector that I want to be able to use in a case statement in PROC SQL.  I haven't found anything from my research.  Let me explain with an example.

I have a vector of phone brands:

```
phone_brand
nokia
samsung
apple
microsoft
sony
motorolla
```

I want to make a PROC SQL statement on another table with more data, but I want to create an indicator that will tell me if the phone_brand field of the table matches the matrix.  So the idea of the code would be something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select id
      ,date
      ,case when index(home.phone_brand,'vector values') > 0 then 1 else 0
       end as vector_ind
from ods.home;
quit;
```

I need this because the vector that I have will be dynamic, but doesn't have any sort of key to identify the brands.  So I have to use the index function to search for a match.  If I can't find a way to do it with the vector I think my only other option will be to update the code manually every time the data in the vector changes like this:

```
,case when index(home.phone_brand,'nokia') > 0 then 1
     when index(home.phone_brand,'samsung) > 0 then 1
     when index(home.phone_brand,'apple) > 0 then 1
     .......
     else 0 end as vector_ind
```

This will be cumbersome and difficult to scale if the number of brands in the vector increase significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the IN operator.

```
proc sql;
select name , sex , age
     , name in ('Alfred','Carol') as vector_ind
from sashelp.class
;
```

You could also store the list in a macro variable

```
%let vector = 'Alfred','Carol' ;
```

And then use the macro variable in your query.

```
select name , sex , age
     , name in (&vector) as vector_ind
from sashelp.class
;
```

or store it in a dataset,

```
create table vector as 
  select name 
  from sashelp.class 
  where name in (&vector)
;
```

and use a subquery.

```
select name , sex , age
     , name in (select name from vector) as vector_ind
from sashelp.class
;
```

Or you could combine the last two. Store the values in a dataset but use it to build a macro variable to use in your queries.

```
select catq('1sa',name)
  into :vector separated by ','
  from vector 
;
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Does this only find exact matches though?  I do have some inconsistencies in the data (inconsistent abbreviations and mispellings) that I normally get around by using 'index.'  Do you know how I could adjust for that in this code?

Comment: IN is an exact match, but you can use `upcase(name) in (%upcase(&vector))` to avoid case issues.